# Optimize query with TO CHAR function

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, oracle11g, ssrs-2008

I have a rather large SELECT query, but it would run only about 1.5/2 minutes normally, but upon adding one other piece, i had to use a to_char function on a left outer join to resolve an "invalid number" error.

Now, my query takes 10+ min and has timed out in SSRS.  Is there a better alternative to to_char? I am using it in this clause:

`left outer join ifsapp.customer_order_line col
    on col.order_no = fa.order_ref_1
   and col.line_no = fa.order_ref_2
   and col.rel_no = fa.order_ref_3
   and to_char(col.line_item_no) = fa.order_ref_4`

The line_item_no field is a "number" type and the order_ref_4 field is a "varchar2(20)" type.

Is there a cast or conversion I can use to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to repair the field order_ref_4 before to start the report. If you create index (if you have grants), you should do it on (order_no,line_no,col.rel_no,to_char(col.line_item_no) ). See the explain plan to find the exact problem. The regexp_like + to_number will be not faster too, especially when fa table is large and to_number will make not possible to use an index on fa table.

It is better to have consistent data. Mark as error or repair the false number in order_ref_4. You can find the errors like this

```
select distinct fa.order_ref_4 from fa
where  TRANSLATE(fa.order_ref_4,'0123456789',' ')  is not null
```

If there is only one case which is not a number for sample '*' use this

```
and (fa.order_ref_4 <> '*' and col.line_item_no = fa.order_ref_4)
```

else try this

```
and (TRANSLATE(fa.order_ref_4,'0123456789',' ')  is null and col.line_item_no = fa.order_ref_4)
```

The second one will again make not possible to use the index on fa.

Comment: I can give you suggestion, when you tell me what for errors come in order_ref_4

Comment: If I try to convert fa.order_ref_4 to a number, I get an invalid number error.  If I try to convert col.line_item_no to a character, it times out. If I don't convert either, I get invalid number.

Comment: Do you have rights to update order_ref_4 column? How big is fa table?

Comment: If the column is always supposed to contain numbers then it should be a number column. If it varchar2 because it is *expected* to have different kinds of data then (a) that's a bad design choice, and (b) you can't 'repair' it.

Comment: @AlexPoole don't you have your own answer? What you know about database by OP?

Comment: Your answer assumes the column is only supposed to contain numbers (stored, for some reason, as strings). I'm questioning that assumption, and point out that *if* it's wrong then you can't 'fix' the values. Not sure why that offends you.

Comment: I did some digging and the column fa.order_ref_4 either has a number OR an asterisk.

Comment: than use and (fa.order_ref_4 <> '*' and col.line_item_no = fa.order_ref_4)

Comment: @Mottor that still threw the invalid number error for me.

Comment: Try this from Alex with translate.

Comment: Can you try to put fa.order_ref_4 <> '*'  in the WHERE clause

Comment: @Mottor Translate seemed to work OK.  Took 4 minutes, but that won't time out.  Entirely manageable.

Comment: You can ask the DBA to make for you a suitable (functional) index on fa table . Than will be faster. Have a good day or evening :).

Answer (score 3):

Try adding an index the table with the format of a string:

```
CREATE INDEX char_ind
 ON ifsapp.customer_order_line (TO_CHAR(line_item_no));
```

Comment: I am not familiar with doing this... where do I put this portion of code? In the join? or somewhere else.

Comment: No, its a DDL comand. Just execute it once out side of the query and the table will have this index permanently @DominicG.

Comment: Ok.  Sorry if this is a dumb question, but can I do that within SSRS?

Comment: I assume yes,but I don't know ssrs. Try executing it the aame as you execute a select query

Comment: Unfortunately I can't quite do that.  Damn.  If there is a way to do this in SSRS, I would be golden.

Comment: http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2011/03/reporting-services-creating-a-index-table-of-contents-with-hyperlink-shortcuts/ try following the steps in this link mate.

Comment: This is what is known as a "functional index".  Right now the problem you're having is that using the TO_CHAR makes it so your current index is not utilized.  Adding this should resolve that, but just know that it's not necessarily "free"!  It takes take up additional table space to store this index, so bear that in mind if disk space is an issue.

Comment: @DominicG. - Are you able to create a TEMP table of `ifsapp.customer_order_line` and then create the index on that? SSRS will let you put multiple steps in the dataset query.

Comment: Ask your DBA to create the index.

Answer (score 1):

Using `to_char()` is causing all of the `line_item_no` values - or at least all those in rows that match other filters, depending on the optimiser's chosen plan - to be converted to strings before they can be compared with `order_ref_4`. As well as adding a small amount overhead just to do that conversion, more seriously it will prevent any index on that column from being used. The difference in execution times suggests that is what is happening - you can look at the execution plans for your old and new queries to see what else might have changed.

You could check whether the `order_ref_4` value can be converted to a number, on the right-hand side of the comparison, which will allow any index on `line_item_no` to still be used:

```
   and col.line_item_no =
     case when regexp_like(fa.order_ref_4, '^\d+$')
       then to_number(fa.order_ref_4) end
```

If it has any non-numeric characters then it will try to match null - which won't match with `=` of course, as nulls can't be compared with equality. This will also only work for positive integers (as a minus sign or decimal character won't match `\d`), but I imagine a line item number *will* be an integer.

If the `regexp_like()` is too slow, which it may be if you have a lot of datam then you could use `translate()` instead - same idea as in Mottor's answer, but still protecting the `to_number()`:

```
   and col.line_item_no =
     case when translate(fa.order_ref_4, '0123456789', ' ') is null
       then to_number(fa.order_ref_4) end
```

Storing different types of data in generic text fields throws up these sort of problems. You should really store data in columns of the right type - numbers as number, dates as dates, etc.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot convert fa.order_ref_4 to a number.  I get the invalid number error.

Comment: @DominicG. - you get that inside the case expression? I understand you got that from the (implicit) conversion before you tried `to_char()`; the case is supposed to avoid that. Oracle short-circuits that so it won't attempt the `to_number()` unless the pattern matches, i.e. it's all-digits.

Comment: Testing out the case expression now -- sorry, initially only tried to cast order_ref_4 as a number.  Been running for 7 minutes and counting unfortunately.

Comment: If there is a lot of data then the regex might be too slow; you could use `translate()` as Mottor showed instead. But really you need to look at the execution plans to see what it's doing.